# axios returns data 3 times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I use the following structure to get data using axios

```
export const PostScreen = ({route, navigation}) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [data, setData] = React.useState();

    const {id, title} = route.params;

    navigation.setOptions({
        title: title
    });

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('https://6420bd1382bea25f6d0666b6.mockapi.io/test/' + id)
            .then(({data}) => {setData(data)})
            .catch(e => Alert.alert('Error', 'Error'))
            .finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
    }, []);

    console.log(data)

    if(isLoading) {
        return <Loading/>
    }

    return (
      <View>
          <PostImage source={{uri: data.imageUrl}}/>
          <PostText>{data.text}</PostText>
      </View>
    );
}
```

when outputting to the console, undefined is displayed first, and then the data 2 times, does axios make 3 requests? The application works as expected, but I was confused at the moment. I would not want 2 extra requests to go to the server

I hope this is just my misunderstanding of how axios works, and you can explain it to me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: 3 renders. Initial, after setData, after setIsLoading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does axios make 3 requests?

In your browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, how many instances of this request do you observe?  That's how many requests are being made.

Taking a step back, observe that the code shown has *more to it* than *just Axios*.  You appear to be making the assumption that *the whole thing* is "Axios", and that is not at all the case.  What you have here is *a React component*.  And *one thing* that React component does is invoke an HTTP request via Axios.

*Another thing* that React component does, on every render, is this:

```
console.log(data)
```

This is *entirely separate from and unrelated to* the Axios request.  The two have *nothing* to do with one another.  All this line of code does is output the current value of `data` to the console.  And it does this every time the component renders.

So it will output a value *at least once*, when the component initially renders.  After that, what causes a component to re-render?  State changes.  For example, this one:

```
setData(data)
```

And/or this one:

```
setIsLoading(false)
```

Since these two state updates are happening in different callbacks of a Promise chain, the component could very well be re-rendering between those two operations.  You can reduce it to *one* re-render by queuing both state updates synchronously:

```
axios.get('https://6420bd1382bea25f6d0666b6.mockapi.io/test/' + id)
    .then(({data}) => {
        setData(data);
        setIsLoading(false);
    })
    .catch(e => Alert.alert('Error', 'Error'));
```

State updates themselves are still asynchronous, but queueing multiple updates synchronously would result in them being batched and triggering only one re-render of the component.

Comment: But if I put setIsLoading(false) in then, then. in case of an error, the loading will continue forever. Although, on the other hand, what does it matter what to show: loading or emptiness if the data is not received. Thanks for your reply!